# $\mathbb{R}$-bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles

Why a principal $\mathbb{R}$-bundle is always trivial?

I know that a principal bundle of the form $(E,B,\pi,G)$ is trivial if and only if it admits a global section $f:B\to E$. So which section should I take? Is there a simpler way to prove this property?

Comment: Maybe the zero section?

Comment: @Berci: I think the OP is asking about principal bundles with structure group $\Bbb{R}$. It is not obvious that such things are vector bundles.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, I meant principal bundles with structure group $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a differential geometry question suppose that $B$ is paracompact, let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ a trivialisation, and $f_i$ a partition of unity subordinate to $(U_i)$. Let $h_i:U_1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $h_i(x)=1$, define $h=\sum_i f_ih_i$ since $f_i\geq 0, h_i>0$.

Comment: I don't think that things are that easy, at least what you have written needs interpretation. Oberserve in particular, that there is no well defined addition on  sections of a prinicipal $\mathbb R$-bundle. You can certainly use partitions of unity to glue two local sections to a section defined on a larger subset. To prove triviality of the bundle in this way, you have to invoke a finite atlas theorem. I don't know whether there is a direct way to blue local sections to a global section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is a more rigorous version of what **Tsemo Aristide** was going for.

**General setup**

Fix a Lie group $G$ and a manifold $F$ on which $G$ acts simply transitively. Then, for a manifold $M$, let us denote by $\mathrm{Prin}_{F,G}(M)$ the isomorphism classes of principal $F$-bundles $T\to M$ with structure group $G$. In other words, such an object is

- a smooth manifold $T$ with an action of $G$,
- a map of smooth manifolds $p\colon T\to M$ which is $G$-equivairant (where $M$ is given the trivial $G$-action),
- there exists an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $M$ such that for all $i$ one has a diffeomorphism $p^{-1}(U_i)\cong F\times U_i$ such that the following diagram commutes $$\begin{matrix}p^{-1}(U_i) &  & \to & & F\times U_i\\ & \searrow & & \swarrow & \\ & & U_i & & \end{matrix}$$ (where the left diagonal arrow is $p$ and the right diagonal arrow is the projection map $F\times U_i\to U_i$), and such that this isomorphism is equivariant for the $G$-actions on both sides (where $G$ acts on $F\times U_i$ by $g(f,u):=(gf,u)$).

Then, if we let $\mathcal{O}_{M,G}$ be sheaf on $M$ given by

$$\mathcal{O}_{M,G}(U):=\mathrm{Hom}_\text{smooth}(U,G)$$

(where we multiply two maps by $$(f_f f_2)(u):=f_1(u)f_2(u)$$ which makes sense since $G$ is a group), then there is a bijection

$$\mathrm{Prin}_{F,G}(M)\cong \check{H}^1(M,\mathcal{O}_{M,G})$$

where this right-hand side is the first Cech cohomology. For the definition of this cohomology set see [Wedhorn, §7.2], and for this bijection see [Wedhorn, Equation (8.8)].

**$\mathbb{R}$-bundles**

To apply this setup to study $\mathbb{R}$-bundles, we observe that the set of isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{R}$-bundles on $M$ is precisely $\mathrm{Prin}_{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}}(M)$ where $G=F=\mathbb{R}$ and $G=\mathbb{R}$ acts on $F=\mathbb{R}$ by left translation.

> **Claim:** Every $\mathbb{R}$-bundle on $M$ is isomorphic to the trivial $\mathbb{R}$-bundle $\mathbb{R}\times M$.

To prove this, we must show that $\check{H}^1(M,\mathcal{O}_{M,\mathbb{R}})$ is trivial. Note though that

$$\mathcal{O}_{M,\mathbb{R}}(U)=\mathrm{Hom}_\text{smooth}(U,\mathbb{R})$$

is nothing but the sheaf of smooth functions on $M$ which, for simplicitly, I just denote by $\mathcal{C}^\infty_M$. Now, the point here is then the following lemma which uses the existence of partitions of unity:

> **Lemma ([Wedhorn, Theorem 9.11]):** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Then, $\mathcal{C}^\infty_M$ is a soft sheaf.

I won't define what this means exactly here (see [Wedhorn, §9.1] for details), but in essence it means that every section of $\mathcal{C}^\infty_M$ over a closed set $Z$ can be extended to a smooth function on all of $M$. You can see how proving such a thing would use bump functions, which in turn use the existence of partitions of unity (see [Wedhorn, Lemma 9.10 and Theorem 9.11] to have this fleshed out).

There is then the following general, but powerful fact from the theory of cohomology of sheaves.

> **Proposition ([Wedhorn, Theorem 9.14]):** For a paracompact Hausdorff space $X$, and any soft sheaf of groups $\mathcal{G}$, the set $\check{H}^1(X,\mathcal{G})$ is a singleton.

The idea of the proof of this result is to refine an open cover $\{U_i\}$ that trivializes any $\mathcal{G}-torsor$ $\mathcal{F}$ (a generalization of a principal bundle) by a closed cover $\{Z_j\}$. Over each $Z_j$ one has a global section of $\mathcal{F}$, and using the softness property one can globalize these sections to a global section of $\mathcal{F}$, which implies its trivial.

We then easily get the following.

*Proof of claim:* This just comes from combining the above:

$$\{\mathbb{R}\text{-bundles on M}\}/\text{iso.}\cong \mathrm{Prin}_{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}}(M)\cong \check{H}^1(M,\mathcal{C}^\infty_M)=\{\ast\}$$

where the last equality follows since $\mathcal{C}^\infty_M$ is smooth. $\blacksquare$

**References:**

[Wedhorn] Wedhorn, T., 2016. Manifolds, sheaves, and cohomology. Springer Spektrum.

Comment: This is way too complicated: It follows from the obstruction theory that every bundle over a base which is a CW complex and has contractible fibers has a section.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's fine you feel that way, but I don't know what the 'obstruction theory' you are referring to means, so clearly for me this is less complicated. To me this is basic--essentially trivial if you know the first thing about the theory of sheaves. I'm not claiming that this is a god-given way to answer the question, just an explanation of what the other answerer was trying to say (I think).